# How to await/access nested proxy values in Nuxt plugin?

Tags: javascript, json, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have a plugin for PostHog. In this plugin I want to initialize my Pinia store, so I can use the store data. The problem that I have is that the plugin loads before my store is loaded, so I receieve a proxy with nested objects.

How can I extract the data that I need from this proxy, so I can use it in my plugin? Or, how can I make sure that my store is filled with data before my plugin initializes?

I have tried every combination possible with `JSON.stringify`, `JSON.parse`, and  `...userStore.activeUser`, but I keep getting a null result.

This is my JSON object when I stringify it.

```
{
   "$id":"user",
   "activeUser":null
}
```

I'm trying to acces `activeUser.actieveBasisgroep`. `activeUser` Should be filled with the code below.

```
{
   "user":"123",
   "actieveBasisgroep":{
      "id":"dde240a0-e5bb-459a-abde-6ca708861d87"
   }
}
```

The plugin looks like this:

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {
  const userStore = useUserStore();
  console.log(JSON.stringify({ ...userStore }));
  console.log(toRaw({ ...userStore.activeUser }));

  if (toRaw({ ...userStore.activeUser }).actieveBasisgroep) {
    console.log('nope');
  }

  return '';
});
```

And my store is filled like this:

```
export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      activeUser: null as null | ActiveUser,
    };
  },
  // Setters, getters, actions ...
```

Comment: Are you trying the display the active user inside the `template` or no?

Comment: @ReaganM No, inside a Nuxt3 plugin

Answer (score 0):

This is because Pinia is not instigated in Vue because Vue it's self not ready, it is from the Vue instance that uses pinia ( `app.use(pinia)` ) where your stores look to find the top level instance of pinia automatically, in cases like these, this when you have to manually let a store know what instance of Pinia to use.

To use Pinia before full initialization of Vue or for example in router navigation guards (anything outside of the scope of an instance of Vue) you need to pass a top level shared instance to a store, the same one you are giving to Vue it's self.

You can achieve this by assigning the Pinia instance to a global scope like `window.Pinia = createPinia()` and do `useUserStore(window.Pinia)` or use some Bus based practice, I preferer to use the simple JS native module approach:

```js
// src/pinia.ts

const pinia = createPinia()

export default pinia
```

```js
// main.ts
import pinia from '@/pinia'

...
app.use(pinia) // Ensure your app uses the shared instance you created.
...
```

```js
// src/plugins/myPlugin
import pinia from '@/pinia'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {
  const userStore = useUserStore(pinia); // Give store shared pinia instance

  console.log(JSON.stringify({ ...userStore }));
  console.log(toRaw({ ...userStore.activeUser }));

  if (toRaw({ ...userStore.activeUser }).actieveBasisgroep) {
    console.log('nope');
  }

  return '';
});
```